# Android animating recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created a recyclerview with a list of 'events'.This works fine for a list of events that is below 5. but as soon as i get 6 or more events in the list the last event will not expand when clicked, instead it dissapears. the closing animation also stops working with more than 6 events in the list.

how it should behave:

- User taps event > view expands to full screen
- User taps an expanded event > view collapses back to it's original size
- User taps an event while another event is expanded > expanded event is set to original height en tapped event expands to fullscreen

current behavior:

- User taps event > all views expand correctly except for the last item in the list
- User taps expanded event > view collapses but does not animate
- User taps an event while another event is expanded > expanded event collapses and tapped event expands correctly
- User taps the last event in the list > the event dissapears (probably decreased it's size to below 0)

I know it probably has something to do with the way the recyclerview reuses its views when they are out of the screen. To fix this i check the position of the tapped event by the eventId instead of the position in the list, but this still leaves the issues that i talked about above.

```
public class EventRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context c;
    private List<Event> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private RelativeLayout container;
    private int screenheight;
    private EventListFragment eventListFragment;
    private int expandedPosition = -1;
    private static final String TAG = "EventRecyclerAdapter";

    public interface ItemClickedListener {
        void itemClicked(int position);
    }

    private ItemClickedListener itemClickedListener;

    public EventRecyclerAdapter(List<Event> itemlist, Context c, EventListFragment eventListFragment, ItemClickedListener listener) {
        this.items = itemlist;
        this.c = c;
        this.eventListFragment = eventListFragment;
        this.itemClickedListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenheight = size.y;

        // Get the screen height from the device
        Resources r = c.getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        screenheight -= px;

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        Event event = items.get(position);
        // - get data from your itemsData at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData
        viewHolder.tvName.setText(event.getName());
        viewHolder.tvLocation.setText(event.getLocation().getName());
        viewHolder.tvDate.setText(Helper.dateDoubleToString(event.getStartDate()));
        viewHolder.tvTicketCount.setText(String.valueOf(event.getNumberOfTickets()));
        viewHolder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        viewHolder.eventId = event.getId();

        // Load the background image
        if (event.getEventImageId() != null) {
            Picasso.with(c).load(Helper.imageUrlString(event.getEventImageId())).into(viewHolder.background);
            ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
            matrix.setSaturation(0);

            ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
            viewHolder.background.setColorFilter(filter);
        }

        // Check if the view needs to be expanded, collapsed or just drawn normally.
        if (expandedPosition == event.getId()) {
            if (event.expanded) {
                collapseView(viewHolder, event);
            } else if (!event.expanded) {
                expandView(viewHolder, position, event);
            }
        } else {
            setContainerHeight(viewHolder, event);
        }
    }

    private void expandView(final EventRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int pos, Event event) {
        ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(
                viewHolder.container,
                viewHolder.container.getHeight(),
                screenheight
        );
        resizeAnimation.setDuration(Constants.ANIMATION_SPEED);
        resizeAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                viewHolder.infoContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.closeIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemClickedListener.itemClicked(pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
        viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
        viewHolder.expanded = true;

        event.expanded = true;
    }

    private void collapseView(final EventRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Event event) {
        ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(
                viewHolder.container,
                viewHolder.container.getHeight(),
                getContainerCollapsedHeight()
        );
        resizeAnimation.setDuration(Constants.ANIMATION_SPEED);

        viewHolder.infoContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.closeIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
        viewHolder.expanded = false;
        event.expanded = false;
}

    private void setContainerHeight(EventRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Event event) {
        viewHolder.container.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, getContainerCollapsedHeight()));
        viewHolder.infoContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.closeIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        event.expanded = false;
        viewHolder.expanded = false;
    }

    private int getContainerCollapsedHeight() {
        int containerHeight;
        // Define the item containers height
        if (items.size() <= 3) {
            containerHeight = screenheight / items.size();
        } else {
            containerHeight = screenheight / 3;
        }
        return containerHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Clear all current data and swap add the new data list.
     * The expanded position also gets reset
     * @param events
     */
    public void swap(List<Event> events) {
        this.items.clear();
        this.items.addAll(events);
        this.expandedPosition = -1;

        Log.v(TAG,"SWAP SIZE : " + items.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvLocation, tvDate, tvTicketCount;
        public TextView tvName;
        public ImageView background;
        public View container;
        public View infoContainer;
        public TextView closeIcon;
        public int eventId;
        public boolean expanded = false;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            tvName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvLocation = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
            tvDate = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            background = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.background);
            tvTicketCount = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_count);
            container = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_container);
            infoContainer = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.info_container);
            closeIcon = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.close_icon);

            infoContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Activity mainActivity = (Activity) c;
                    FragmentManager fm = mainActivity.getFragmentManager();
                    //add
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_to_top, R.animator.slide_from_bottom);
                    ft.addToBackStack(ft.toString());
                    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, EventFragment.newInstance(items.get(getAdapterPosition())), Constants.EVENT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                    //commit change
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });

            container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    expandedPosition = eventId;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

i think it's somehow running the `collapseView` method when i tap the last item in the list, causing its height to become below 0. But i'm unable to figure out why this is happening.
I hope someone is able to spot what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in OnClilck of recycleview Item

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
     if (!large)
        {
            params.height = 2 * view.getHeight();     
        } else {
            params.height = view.getHeight()/2;
        }
        large = !large;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i don't want to transition between activities. It's only supposed to increase the height of the row to that of the full screen, the user is still able to scroll through the rest of the list.